# React: Setinterval is not stopping even after clearing the timer using clearInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I have made a basic slideshow demo where on checking the checkbox slideshow is enabled. Problem is that once enabled slide show can't be disabled even if I uncheck the checkbox. As per muy understanding, I'm learning the timer and also nullifying the state storing the timer but the slide show keep on going.

Specifically this part gets invoked on checkbox update:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (isTrue) {
    setSlideTimer(() => {
      return setInterval(() => {
        forwardButton.current.click();
      }, slideDuration);
    });
  } else {
    clearInterval(slideTimer);
    setSlideTimer(null);
  }
}, [isTrue]);
```

From browser logs it is evident that timer indeed got cleared. Though there is a warning `"... component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled"` but I'm not sure if that's the culprit here.

Comment: I thought you would pass the setInterval as an argument, not a function returning set interval? The reason you're getting the error is because it wants you to set the value to `isChecked` isntead of the timer. This way, the value the onChange changes is the value it represents.

Comment: @asyncawait I updated the useEffect hook. Now I'm directly passing the setInterval to setSlideTimer. I'm not sure exactly where you want be to "set the value of isChecked instead of the timer", can you please provide a code snippet? So far, I'm getting the same result :(

Comment: I got what you mean by changing setInterval in input to isChecked. I did that as well, still no luck.

Comment: If you create a codepen or repo I'll try fiddling around with it. I'm not confident enough in my experience with react to give an answer from the information at hand.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem. Issue arrised because I was incorrectly setting boolean into a state meant to store timer.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

The issue is that you've a missing dependency on the `sliderTimer` state.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isTrue) {
      setSlideTimer(() => {
        return setInterval(() => {
          forwardButton.current.click();
        }, slideDuration);
      });
    } else {
      clearInterval(slideTimer);
      setSlideTimer(null);
    }
  }, [isTrue]);
```

## Solution

Don't generally store timer ids in state. Use a React ref is you need to access the timer id *outside* the `useEffect` hook, otherwise just cache it locally within the `useEffect` hook's callback. In this case you will want to use a ref to hold the `sliderTimer` id value so it can also be cleared in the case the component unmounts.

Example:

```
const sliderTimerRef = React.useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  // Clear any running intervals on component unmount
  return () => clearInterval(sliderTimerRef.current);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isTrue && forwardButton.current) {
    sliderTimerRef.current = setInterval(
      forwardButton.current.click,
      slideDuration
    );
  } else {
    clearInterval(sliderTimerRef.current);
  }
}, [isTrue]);
```

### Additional issue

> From browser logs it is evident that timer indeed got cleared. Though
> there is a warning `"... component is changing an uncontrolled input of type checkbox to be controlled"` but I'm not sure if that's the
> culprit here.

This is typically the case when the `value` or `checked` prop changes from an undefined to a defined value. Ensure whatever the checked state is that it is initially defined, even if just `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (isChecked) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        forwardButton.current.click();
      }, 1000); // change it
    }

    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log('Clear timer');
    };
  }, [isChecked]);
```

Comment: if you need explanation then let me know ? how this thing work.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the `setTimeout()` method. For this you would need to create a new state `clicks` (or any other name) that will trigger the `useEffect` every time it changes, allowing `setTimeout` to work as `setInterval`

```
const [clicks, setClicks] = useState(0)

useEffect(() => {
  if(isChecked){
    setTimeout(() => { 
      forwardButton.current.click()
      setClicks(clicks + 1)
    }, slideDuration)
  }
}, [isChecked, clicks])
```